# Assigning a whole DataStructure its nullind array

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Some context before the question.

Imagine file FileA having around 50 fields of different types.  Instead of all programs using the file, I tried having a service program, so the file could only be accessed by that service program.  The programs calling the service would then receive a DataStructure based on the file structure, as an ExtName.  I use SQL to recover the information, so, basically, the procedure would go like this :

Datastructure shared by service program :

```
D FileADS       E  DS                 ExtName(FileA) Qualified
```

Procedure called by programs :

```
P getFileADS      B                   Export 
D                 PI              N
D  PI_IDKey                      9B 0 Const
D  PO_DS                              LikeDS(FileADS)

D LocalDS       E DS                  ExtName(FileA) Qualified
D NullInd         S              5i 0 Array(50)    <-- Since 50 fields in fileA

 //Code
 Clear LocalDS;
 Clear PO_DS;

 exec sql
   SELECT *
   INTO   :LocalDS :nullind
   FROM   FileA
   WHERE  FileA.ID = :PI_IDKey;

 If SqlCod <> 0;
   Return *Off;
 EndIf;

 PO_DS = LocalDS;
 Return *On;

P getFileADS      E
```

So, that procedure will return a datastructure filled with a record from FileA if it finds it.

Now my question : Is there any way I can assign the %nullind(field) = *On without specifying EACH 50 fields of my file?

Something like a loop

```
 i = 1;
 DoW (i <= 50);
   if nullind(i) = -1;
     %nullind(datastructure.field) = *On;
   endif;
   i++;
 EndDo;
```

Cause let's face it, it'd be a pain to look each fields of each file every time.

I know a simple chain(n) could do the trick

```
 chain(n) PI_IDKey FileA FileADS;
```

but I really was looking to do it with SQL.

Thank you for your advices!

OS Version : 7.1

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but will offer a suggestion.  Instead of returning a data structure, instead write 50 getFieldName procedures that will return each field individually.  There's definitely a lot more upfront setup, but then you'll further to decouple the file i/o from the calling program.  By going the data structure method, if any field changes or is added, all calling programs must be recompiled.  An old coworker and I wrote a utility to do create a file encapsulated service program for a file, though it's not in the best place for sharing it currently.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll be better off in the long run by eliminating `SELECT *` and supplying a SELECT list of the 50 field names.

Next, consider these two web pages -- [Meaningful Names for Null Indicators](http://www.itjungle.com/fhg/fhg102908-story02.html) and [Embedded SQL and null indicators](http://forums.iprodeveloper.com/forums/aft/131211). The first shows an example of assigning names to each null indicator to match the associated field names. It's just a matter of declaring a based DS with names, based on the address of your null indicator array. The second points out how a null indicator array can be larger than needed, so future database changes won't affect results. (Bear in mind that the page shows a null array of 1000 elements, and the memory is actually relatively tiny even at that size. You can declare it smaller if you think it's necessary for some reason.)

You're creating a proc that you'll only write once. It's not worth saving the effort of listing the 50 fields. Maybe if you had many programs using this proc and you had to create the list each time it'd be a slight help to use `SELECT *`, but even then it's not a great idea.

A matching template DS for the 50 data fields can be defined in the /COPY member that will hold the proc prototype. The template DS will be available in any program that brings the proc prototype in. Any program that needs to call the proc can simply specify LIKEDS referencing the template to define its version in memory. The template DS should probably include the QUALIFIED keyword, and programs would then use their own DS names as the qualifying prefix. The null indicator array can be handled similarly.

However, it's not completely clear what your actual question is. You show an example loop and ask if it'll work, but you don't say if you had a problem with it. It's an array, so a loop can be used much like you show. But it depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish with it.

Comment: In fact, the loop was part of the question.  I was looking for a way where I wouldn't need to return the nullind array.  Because when I return the file datastructure as a parameter, the %nullind() BIF will give me the right value, it'll be initiated.  So I was wondering if there was a way to loop the DS to assign all of it's nullind, instead of doing it individually for all field.  Is it clearer?

Also, I kept the SELECT * because whatever happened to the file, this function is supposed to always return every fields.

Comment: Though it can`'return every field`, that can risk "unpredictable results" in programs that call the proc unless every calling module is also recompiled to match or unless various protective coding methods are used. The "unpredictable results" can include undetected data corruption that might go on for a long time, potentially never being noticed (until weeks/months later after a long series of errors that might not be tracked). If a file change causes the proc to return a DS with 51 fields and the calling proc only knows about 50 fields, where will that new data go?

Comment: So anyway, my original question was to know if there is a way to set the %nullind(field) of a DS without listing each of its field.  Should I understand with you original answer that I can't?

Comment: @ArnaudMongrain I went ahead and posted an answer. It wasn't completely clear **exactly** what you were asking.

Comment: I'll to make it a bit clearer today in my original post, but the general idea is that I was looking for a way to assign all of the ExtName DS fields at once their nullind array position.  Instead of doing something like "%nullind(field1) = nullInArr(1); %nullind(field2) = nullindArr(2);...".  Would that be clearer?

Comment: @ArnaudMongrain That makes less sense. The values are already set. There is no need for what you ask about in this comment. If nullInArr(1) is set to indicate a null value for the first null-capable field, then %nullind(Fld1) already has a '1' value. There is no need to assign values back and forth between them. If one is set, the other changes automatically because they are simply two different ways to refer to the same thing. To make use of %NULLIND(fieldname), you do need to compile with the ALWNULL(*USRCTL) keyword.

Comment: When the Select Into is done, the data structure will be filled, and so will the nullind array.  But as far as I know, the "SQL" part won't initialise the %nullind() indicator for a field of the DS, will it?  Cause if I remember correctly, my tests say otherwise.

Comment: Ah! Though they are "the same", they aren't actually intended to be used at the same time inside a single program. In general, a null-indicator array would be coded in a SQLRPGLE program, and %NULLIND() would be used for native I/O over an externally-described database file. So, native I/O might read a record from a table that was UPDATEd by SQL using a null-indicator array. The appropriate %NULLIND()s are available to the non-SQL RPG program, _essentially_ having been set by SQL.

Answer (score 0):

**for old school rpg just include the nulls in the data structure populated with the select statement.**

```
select col1, ifnull(col1), col2, ifnull(col2), etc.  into :dsfilewithnull where f.id = :id;
```

**for old school rpg that can't handle nulls remove them with the select statement.**

```
select coalesce(col1,0), coalesce(col2,' '), coalesce(col3, :lowdate) into :dsfile where f.id = :id;
```

The second method would be easier to use in a legacy environment.

pass the key by value to the procedure so you can use it like a built in function.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to your question would be to make the array part of a data structure, and assign *all'0' to the data structure.

```
dcl-ds nullIndDs;
  nullInd      Ind Dim(50);
end-ds;

nullIndDs = *all'0';
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by jmarkmurphy is an example of assigning all zeros to an array of indicators. For the example that you show in your question, you can do it this way:

```
 D NullInd         S              5i 0 dim(50)

  /free
    NullInd(*) = 1 ;
    Nullind(*) = 0 ;

    *inlr = *on ;
    return ;
  /end-free
```

That's a complete program that you can compile and test. Run it in debug and stop at the first statement. Display NullInd to see the initial value of its elements. Step through the first statement and display it again to see how the elements changed. Step through the next statement to see how things changed again.

As for "how to do it in SQL", that part doesn't make sense. SQL sets the values **automatically** when you FETCH a row. Other than that, the array is used by the host language (RPG in this case) to communicate values back to SQL. When a SQL statement runs, it again **automatically** uses whatever values were set. So, it either is used automatically by SQL for input or output, or is set by your host language statements. There is nothing useful that you can do 'in SQL' with that array.